# Creating DEM from multiple .las files using LAStools in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, lidar, lastools

I am attempting to create a DEM for a raster large dataset, with over 500 .las files. Within the `las2dem` tool, within the LAStools toolbox there is not an option to select an entire folder, nor can you do so manually.

Thus, I tried creating a DEM for each file; however, an output was not generated. I saved both the file location and directory, but got no output. How do I use this tool?

Also I attempted to merge some of my .las files together using the `lasmerge` tool and got no output. I also ensured the file location an directory was saved properly.

Answer (score 3):

Create a LAS dataset. You can add files to this dataset by folder, so you don't have to manually add all 500 files. Use the "LAS Dataset to Raster" tool. It will give you a raster from the input.

Comment: We focused explaining why OP's workflow did not work and you provided a clean solution (+1).

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to create a DEM for a raster large dataset, with over 500 las files. Within the "las2dem" tool, within the LAStools toolbox there is not an option to select an entire folder, nor can you do so manually.

You can automate processing multiple .las files with the [LAStools Production](https://rapidlasso.com/2014/04/03/new-lastools-production-and-lastools-pipelines-for-arcgis/) toolbox which will take folders and wildcards as inputs parameters. See more in this post: [Clipping from a tiled LAS dataset with LASTools (for ArcGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122496/clipping-from-a-tiled-las-dataset-with-lastools-for-arcgis/159140#159140)

About `las2dem` and `lasmerge` are not working we need more details, for example, how did you set them (the command-line parameterization)?

Nonetheless, I suggest reading the following posts:

- [Converting LiDAR data to raster (DEM/DSM) for ArcGIS input?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/converting-lidar-data-to-raster-dem-dsm-for-arcgis-input/56710#56710)
- [Merging more than 9 input files with lasmerge?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164377/merging-more-than-9-input-files-with-lasmerge/164379#164379)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. The LAStools toolbox is for single files. The LAStools Production toolbox is for many of files (i.e. usually a folder of tiles).