# Clip multiple .las files data to polygon shapefile using FUSION

Tags: clip, lidar, las, command-line, fusion

I followed [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/how-to-clip-las-data-using-shapefile-polygons-and-open-source-software) in order to clip .las data based off of a polygon shapefile.  However I have over 100 .las files I need to clip based off of this polygon and merged into a single .lasd file and I would like to clip them all at once.

The [FUSION manual](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/FUSION_manual.pdf#page=118) says on page 114 that you can substitute a list of file names instead of a single .las file in order to run the command on a batch of files.  I have created a text file list based off of the directory where the .las files are located but I get an error stating that no points fall within the polygon.  When I run the command against a single file I do get valid output.

Here is my command:

```
C:\fusion\polyclipdata C:\_projects\LiDAR\WVC_boundary\WVC_boundary.shp C:\_projects\LiDAR\WVC.las E:\2013_LiDAR_Final\LAS_Final\LAS_StatePlaneFeet\tiles2.txt
```

Here is an example of my text file containing a list of the file names:

```
 Volume in drive E is PW_GIS
 Volume Serial Number is 74B7-6DCC

 Directory of E:\2013_LiDAR_Final\LAS_Final\LAS_StatePlaneFeet

07/15/2015  01:46 PM    <DIR>          .
07/15/2015  01:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/12/2014  02:46 PM       126,366,636 12TVK0400078000_SPC.LAS
08/12/2014  02:48 PM       209,419,456 12TVK0400079000_SPC.LAS
```

etc...

Can someone help me create a proper list of file names to be able to run this command against a collection of .las files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, this is a DOS thing, not fusion... you want to use [DIR /B](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm) to generate a list of just the file names (/b means brief). If you want the full paths use DIR /B/S - this will also search all sub directories.

To get a list of just the las files in the current directory into a text file:

```
DIR /B *.LAS > FileList.txt
```

(the `>` means redirect the output into a text file)

To get a list of all las files in the current directory (and all sub directories) with full paths:

```
DIR /B/S *.LAS > FileList.txt
```

The text file will be in the current directory but if you wish you can also redirect with a full path to the text file (eg `DIR /B/S > C:\SOME\PATH\LIST.TXT`)... to append an existing file use `>>` for example:

```
dir /b/s .\batch1\*.las > c:\some\path\list.txt
dir /b/s c:\other\path\*.las >> c:\some\path\list.txt
```

Creates/overwrites on the first command then appends on the second.

Comment: +1 `dir /b/s *.las > filelist.txt` is what I usually use to create a list of files for FUSION.

Comment: created the file list using the /s flag and now it is working!