# Finding specific area with coordinates out of a lot of LAS data?

Tags: coordinates, lidar, encoding, las, extract-by-mask

I would like to extract spatial data out of a great amount of LAS data.

Unfortunately, there is no index or sth that could help me find which file is for what area.

Also, it is not possible to check all the data as the LAS files are big and can not load all of them.

I would like to know if is there a possibility to extract data out of a lot of LAS data?

Comment: do you have access to FME? PointCloudPropertyExtractor can do what you require https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/PointCloudPropertyExtractor

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: You can try [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154561/clip-multiple-las-files-data-to-polygon-shapefile-using-fusion) approach, but if it requires all las files being loaded into the memory, then you could try a [looping](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150294/clipping-las-data-with-multiple-shapefiles/150502#150502) approach for clipping. But instead of using the looping within the polyfile parameter , one would use the looping within the las file parameter. Taking the example of that answer, something like: (continues)...