# Getting statistics in cross sections at varying heights in LAS files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, statistics, grids-graticules, grid-metrics

I am looking to cross section my forest at varying heights. I have high return LAS data (8 points/m2 and average point spacing of 0.2m) and I am looking to do more than the simple 1, 2, 3 approach of vegetation classification within the LAS file.

I would like to have the flexibility to create multiple cross sections at specific height increments. Looking at, e.g., LASTools and ArcGIS tools, I can't do what I would like. So, I am looking at scripting something myself but I am running into personal knowledge roadblocks.

Firstly, when I create a LAS dataset in Arc each point that is created seems to represent 3500 LiDAR returns; when I run multi-point to single point this does not change.

Secondly, when I try and tile my problem using a fishnet approach the selected points for the current processing tile are not bounded by the tile and produce patterns of selected points well outside the tile (a multi-point property I'm sure).

How do I get at the data to perform my cross sections? Is there a way to play with LAS data outside of a LAS dataset?

UPDATE:

I have successfully sliced up my LAS data using some painful arcpy methods (see code). I am in the process now of running Jae's answer and the Fusion toolbox looks like the way to go in the future.

```
for file in os.listdir(in_las_folder):
    if file.endswith(".las"):
        print '...Working on LAS file {} of {}'.format(current, count)
        process = 2
        las = os.path.join(in_las_folder, file)
        las_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        arcpy.CreateLasDataset_management(las, out_location_las + '\\ld_{}.lasd'.format(las_name), "NO_RECURSION", "", spatial_reference)
        lasd = out_location_las + '\\ld_{}.lasd'.format(las_name)
        arcpy.ChangeLasClassCodes_3d(lasd,"3 0;4 0;5 0")

        print '.....Creating Cross Sections'
        while process <= 38:
            print '........Working on heights between {}m and {}m'.format(process - 2, process)
            raster = out_location_height + '\\h{}_{}'.format(las_name,  process)
            if overwrite_height_model == 'NO':
                if arcpy.Exists(raster):
                    process += 2
                    continue
            print '.........Classify By Height'
            if process == 2:
                value = 20
                arcpy.ClassifyLasByHeight_3d(lasd, "GROUND", "19 1;20 2;21 4;22 6;23 8;24 10;25 12;26 14;27 16;28 18;29 20;30 22;31 24", "NONE", "false", "DEFAULT", "false")
            elif process == 26:
                arcpy.ChangeLasClassCodes_3d(lasd,"19 0;20 0;21 0;22 0;23 0;24 0;25 0;26 0;27 0;28 0;29 0;30 0;31 0")
                arcpy.ClassifyLasByHeight_3d(lasd, "GROUND", "19 24;20 26;21 28;22 30;23 32;24 34;25 36;26 50", "NONE", "false", "DEFAULT", "false")
                value = 20
            arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(lasd, 'las_layer', [value])
            print '.......Creating raster'
            arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion('las_layer', raster, "ELEVATION", "BINNING MAXIMUM NONE", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", "0.5", "1")

            value += 1
            process += 2
        current += 1

        sys.exit()
print 'Creating full rasters'
process = 2
current = 1
while process <= 36:
    print '...Working on {} of {}'.format(current, count)
    for ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
        if int(ras.split('_')[1]) == process:
            height.append(ras)
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(height, out_location_height, 'h{}'.format(process), spatial_reference, '32_BIT_FLOAT', '1', '1')
    for f in height:
        arcpy.DeleteFeature_management(f)
    process += 2
    current += 1
```

Comment: As an alternative approach you can create a raster from non ground LAS points. Then you can use raster calculator to create cross sections. I hope your LIDAR data was taken when the leaves on trees.

Comment: Linking related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183924/retrieving-lidar-metrics-from-relative-vertical-layers-of-point-cloud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re looking for point density at specific height increments, you could look at the FUSION command line tool `DensityMetrics`

Assuming your data are in units of metres:

Step 1: Create a ground file from class 2 (ground) and class 8 (model key) LAS points, at 2 metre spatial resolution.

```
gridsurfacecreate /class:2,8 /minimum YourDrive:\Path\groundfile.dtm 2 M M 0 0 0 0 YourDrive:\Path\*.las
```

Step 2: Create point density slices at 1 metre height intervals using a 20 metre cell size.

```
densitymetrics YourDrive:\Path\groundfile.dtm 20 1 YourDrive:\Path\densities.csv YourDrive:\Path\*.las
```

Step 3: (optional) Rasterize output from the CSV file. Here we will rasterize the 5th column representing densities from the 0-1 metre slice.

```
csv2grid YourDrive:\Path\densities_all_returns.csv 5 return_density_0to1m.asc
```

Comment: Hey Jae! Too funny! Looking at this, I see a lot of things I am not familiar with, but DensityMetrics looks to be exactly what I need. I am trying to follow the manual but am stumped at how to make a 'DTM'. I have only ever dealt with GRID format.

Comment: I’ve edited my original answer with detail of each step.

Comment: do you know why the lowest cell size and height slice I can  go using densitymetrics is 1 and 1? I am trying to get 0.5 and 0.5 but keep getting memory errors. I have tried busting up the LAS file with polyclipdata by 4, 9, and 16 squares but still no go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Profiles: You can work with cross-sections/profiles for LAS data in other software, e.g. **CloudCompare** has a section tool and it's open source. 
   Some other commercial software, like Global Mapper and Quick Terrain Modeler have some **superb profile** tools, if you can obtain a licence.
2. Play with LAS data: ArcGIS doesn't permit field export when creating a shapefile from a LAS file. You can extract the field info from LAS by exporting them in shapefile format (e.g. Global Mapper exports all available fields) or another format (convert to **XYZ, CSV or ASCII** using CloudCompare).
3. Your ~3500 returns per point conversion is obviously not correct. I guess you are using LAS to Multipoint Tool. Try to enter the correct values for Average Point Spacing and Coordinate System, these could be a source of error in your conversion.